# Python reading csv and executing print statement multiple times

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

I have a csv file with 4 fields:

```
JFK,John F Kennedy International,5326,5486 
ORY,Paris-Orly,629,379
MAD,Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas,1428,1151
AMS,Amsterdam Schiphol,526,489
CAI,Cairo International,3779,3584
```

I compare the code entered by the user with the first field of each row. If it matches, I want to print the second field. If it doesn't match with any entry in the CSV, i want to print 'ERROR'.

But 'ERROR' gets printed multiple times even when the code is found.

How can I prevent that?

The code is:

```
if num == 1:
    Adetails = input("Enter airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the UK airport): ")
    while Adetails not in ("LPL", "BOH"):
        Adetails = input("Error three letter airport code invalid. Please enter either LPL or BOH: ")
    Odetails = input("Enter overseas airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the overseas airport): ")
    for row in inputfile:
        if row[0] == Odetails:
            print(row[1])
            repeat = False
        else:
            if row[0] != Odetails:
                print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print something for every line of the CSV you test, either the retrieved data or 'ERROR'.

What you want to do is print 'ERROR' only if you looped to the end without encountering a valid entry. This is a good place for using the `else` block of `for` loops: it only gets executed if you exhaust the loop without `break`ing out of it.

So, your code would be:

```
for row in inputfile:
    if row[0] == Odetails:
        print(row[1])
        break
else: 
    # Executed if we never did break out of the loop, 
    # which means that no matching entry was found
    print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file first. Use import csv at the top.
You can see examples from the csv docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Here's a fix in practice:

```
import csv

Adetails = input("Enter airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the UK airport): ")
while Adetails not in ("LPL", "BOH"):
    Adetails = input("Error three letter airport code invalid. Please enter either LPL or BOH: ")
    Odetails = input("Enter overseas airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the overseas airport): ")
    with open('test5.csv') as csvfile:
        inputfile = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in inputfile:
            # print(row)
            # print(Odetails)
            if row[0] == Odetails:
                print(row[1])
                break
        else:
            print("ERROR")
```

You need to work slower. The key is to work on one step at a time and understand exactly what each variable is (type) and what its value should be. Lots of print statements (commented out here) to be sure things are what you expect, or better use pycharm or another debugger.

This answer presumes there is a file called 'test5.csv'

```
JFK,John F Kennedy International,5326,5486 
ORY,Paris-Orly,629,379 
MAD,Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas,1428,1151 
AMS,Amsterdam Schiphol,526,489 
CAI,Cairo International,3779,3584
```

The output looks like this:

```
(base) [poleguy@dualie so]$ python test5.py
Enter airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the UK airport): a
Error three letter airport code invalid. Please enter either LPL or BOH: LPL
Enter overseas airport details (Please enter the three letter code for the overseas airport): JFK
['JFK', 'John F Kennedy International', '5326', '5486 ']
JFK
John F Kennedy International
```

Comment: please try my 'fix' it should get you un-stuck.

Comment: The first part is irrelevant and uses parameters that don't match the OP's CSV format. Also, it doesn't solve the problem that it prints 'ERROR' 3 unnecessary times.

Comment: Good point Thierry. Those were posted before he had his csv posted. I'll edit.

Comment: Yes, I also missed that the question is asking for it not to repeat the output on every row. He doesn't actually ask that explicitly. It's not clear from the title of the question if that is a problem, or what he intended. There isn't even a question mark anywhere in his question. So really I'm guessing you're right. Updated to fix that.

Comment: The question was not completely clear, I just edited it. For the way to solve the problem, I already answered the same a few minutes ago...;)

Comment: Thierry, I guess you read the question better than I did. Your edit makes it much more clear what he was asking.